# How can I do grouping in my case using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wants to calculate sum of quantity based on Quantity value

**For Example**

```
ItemNo    Quantity
------------------
111       5
111       -2
111       3
112       10
```

I want to do grouping by `ItemNo` and calculate like below

```
ItemNo    Quantity    Positive   Negative
-----------------------------------------
111       6            8           -2
112       10           10          0
```

I tried like this

```
SELECT
    ItemNo,
    Sum(Quantity),
    Case when Quantity >= 0 then sum(quantity) else 0 end POSITIVE,
    Case when Quantity < 0 then sum(quantity) else 0 end Negative
From
    Sales
Group By
    ItemNo,
    Quantity
```

I know this grouping is wrong. How my query should be?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use CASE statement with SUM function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612387/use-case-statement-with-sum-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put the SUM() around your CASE() statement:

```
SELECT
    ItemNo,
    Sum(Quantity),
    SUM(Case when Quantity >= 0 then quantity else 0 end) POSITIVE,
    SUM(Case when Quantity < 0 then quantity else 0 end) Negative
From
    Sales
Group By
    ItemNo;
```

Also, remove `Quantity` from your GROUP BY. You are aggregating `quantity` with a sum() so it's nonsense to GROUP BY it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave this as a comment to JNevill's answer if I had the reputation, but you would also want to give the quantity sum an alias to get the results in the question. For example: `SELECT
    ItemNo,
    Sum(Quantity) Quantity,
    SUM(Case when Quantity >= 0 then Quantity else 0 end) Positive,
    SUM(Case when Quantity < 0 then Quantity else 0 end) Negative
From
    Sales
Group By
    ItemNo;`